# Unable to successfully login as 'controluser' for phpmyadmin, and other user questions

Tags: mysql, macos, phpmyadmin, mamp-pro

I'm using a Mac running OSX 10.7.5.

I've installed MAMP Pro 2.2, using PHP 5.5.3 and MySQL. I successfully upgraded phpMyAdmin to the latest version, 4.0.8, following all the instructions given by MAMP. I've added the config.inc.php file (using the sample provided), not overriding any of the defaults in config.default.php. I have no trouble logging in as root, and I set up the full phpmyadmin database with all of the tables in create_tables.sql.

When I log in as root, I get this warning at the bottom of the phpMyAdmin main page: 
"! Connection for controluser as defined in your configuration failed."

In the mysql.users table, I currently have 2 users: root and pma. The password that appears for "root" is evidently hashed; it's not the password that I use to log in. (I set that password using the MAMP GUI.) But I absolutely cannot figure out how to set the password for pma so I can login as the 'controluser': 'pma'. I've even tried using the exact same password for pma as I use for root, and copied the hashed value for the root password that appears in the root user entry, into the pma user password field (of course, also adding the same login password for pma in the config.inc.php file). Nothing works.

A few more details from my config.inc.php file:

```
$cfg['blowfish_secret'] = '38CharRandomStringEntered...';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = false;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlhost'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controluser'] = 'pma';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlpass'] = 'pmapass' <- I've tried various other values here
```

Two related but slightly different questions:

How do I set up 'pma' to only have control over the phpadmin database?

If I add another user whom I want to only have control over my development database, how do I set that up? I can add the user in mysql.users, but what are the proper privilege settings? And how do I set up the password for a new user so that I don't have the same issues as I've had with the 'pma' user?

Thanks very much. I know I'm very close to getting this right, but I'm frustrated with these last steps.

Answer (score 0):

If you can login as root you can change the password. Under the raw sql area in PHP MyAdmin you can use the `GRANT` syntax to set the password

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON phpadmin.* TO pma@localhost 
   IDENTIFIED BY 'yourpasswordgoeshere'
```

You do a similar thing for your development database just switch `phpadmin` for the name of the development database (and the username / password of course)

Comment: Thanks very much, but when I tried to enter the GRANT statement (logged in as root, of course), I get this reply: "! #1044 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' to database 'phpadmin'". Of course, all privileges, including all Admin privileges, are set to "yes" (checked under Edit Privivleges) for root.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the problem I described in my comment in response to the first answer resolved itself by my shutting down MAMP and rebooting. Now, I have no problems at all setting passwords and privileges. All is good! :-)